# Inline Queries: Is it more performant to run a bunch of little queries, or a single huge one?

Tags: sql-server, performance

For an app I am working on, direction is that we shall use parameterized inline MS-SQL queries to obtain data from our database.

One of the queries I am operating on is rather huge and complex, so I'm considering breaking it out into multiple methods that each run the subquery, and return the value as some string that gets incorporated into the super-query, which gets run to perform some operation.

But this got me thinking about performance; is this 'sub-query' approach more or less performant than keeping my query big and unified?

(Bear in mind, this is my first foray into database technology beyond simple PL/SQL and MS/SQL queries.)

Comment: Using many small queries instead of a big one is the single worst performance mistake you can make.  See [RBAR](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/)

Comment: 1) evaluate whether your query is actually optimized 2) one query may be slower than smaller queries but the time required to connect, retrieve and send back the data is costly

Comment: @Andomar Make that an answer and I'll accept it.  The link was certainly helpful in understanding why RBAR is so bad.

Comment: If only more developers would ask themselves this question.

Comment: @CharlesBurns I disagree - if only more developers would ask themselves *and other developers* this question!  It might save the worldwide economy billions a year in software costs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using many small queries instead of a big one is the single worst performance mistake you can make. [See this simple talk article on RBAR, row by agonizing row.](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/).